# View workflow feedback and approval comments for an item

Tags: content-approval, workflow, list

Using MOSS 2007, I have some standard out-of-the-box 'approval' and 'collect feedback' workflows running against documents in a document library. For example, when a document needs to be verified, the user runs the approval workflow, involving a number of approvers, who all leave comments.

The out-of-the-box email notifications relay these comments back to the user in the body of the email.

However, I want to be able to show in sharepoint a list of all the comments left by approvers.

The only place I can find where comments are actually stored is buried deep in the workflow history list.

Has anyone found a good way of extracting this information to present to users in a nice list? Or can anyone suggest a way I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can try:

a no code solution would be trying to use a CQWP targeted to the history list and host the same in a seperate page.

Comment: Sounds worth a try, thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

You can store comments in each stage by:

1) Creating a Multi line text column(Rich text) in the same SharePoint list.

2) When ever the item is approved or anything then update the current item Column with "Task process: Consolidated comments".

3) Make sure you select "Append changes to the existing text" in the column.